# TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined [ReactJS and Multidimensional Array]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am creating a MultiStep Form using ReduxToolkit to manage the States. On the third step of the form, I get the error "Cannot read property '1' of undefined" when accessing the array `tableArrayData` in the line

```
<BootstrapInput
                type="number"
                name={getUniqueKeyFromArrayIndex(i, j)}
                onChange={onChangeHandler}
                value={tableArrayData[i][j]}
              />
```

Here is link to my code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-browser-3xmlm?file=/src/components/Creator/Algorithm.tsx) and below is the function that generates the table on step 3 of the form.

```
    const createTable = () => {
    compileAnswers();
    let table = [];
    let arrCount = 0;
    // initializeAlgoMatrix();
    // Outer loop to create parent
    for (let i = 0; i < answers.length + 1; i++) {
      let children = [];
      //Inner loop to create children
      for (let j = 0; j < noOfRecommendation + 1; j++) {
        if (i === 0 && j === 0) {
          children.push(
            <td
              style={{
                width: "100px",
                paddingLeft: "20px",
                paddingRight: "50px"
              }}
            >
              {/* Row Header */}
            </td>
          );
          continue;
        }
        if (j === 0) {
          children.push(
            <td
              style={{
                width: "100px",
                paddingLeft: "20px",
                paddingRight: "50px"
              }}
            >
              {answers[arrCount]}
            </td>
          );
          ++arrCount;
          continue;
        }
        if (i === 0) {
          children.push(
            <td
              style={{
                width: "100px",
                paddingLeft: "20px",
                paddingRight: "50px"
              }}
            >
              {"Recommen." + j}
            </td>
          );
        } else {
          children.push(
            <td>
              <BootstrapInput
                type="number"
                name={getUniqueKeyFromArrayIndex(i, j)}
                onChange={onChangeHandler}
                value={tableArrayData[i][j]}
              />
            </td>
          );
        }
      }
      if (i === 0) {
        table.push(<TableHead key={i}>{children}</TableHead>);
      } else {
        table.push(
          <TableRow key={i}>
            <TableCell>{children}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        );
      }
      // console.log(tableCellsData);
      console.log(tableArrayData);
    }
    return table;
  };
```

I have checked many solutions but non seems to fix the issue. Any idea how I could fix this ?

Comment: Then either `tableArrayData` or (more likely) `tableArrayData[i]` is `undefined`.  When you debug, which is it?  If the latter, how many elements are in `tableArrayData` and which element are you trying to access?

Comment: @David It is the latter, tableArrayData[i] is undefined from what I can see in the console when I debug. I defined tableArrayData array and I am not sure how to defined tableArrayData[i] since this array suppose to be initialized based on the question answers in step 1 and recommendation in step 2.
Am really not sure where exactly am missing it.

Comment: Was the array initialized with values?  When the error happens, what is the value of the array?  What is the value of i?

Comment: I found the issue. tableArrayData[i] when i=4 is not initialized because I use (array.lenght + 1) in my for loop. I removed the +1 and everything works fine. Thanks, your guided questions helped the debugging.